# Google script to login, retrieve cookie and get csv to sheets

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, cookies

I can get the cookie with curl -d "_u=user_name" -d "_p=password" --cookie-jar ./cookie https://url.tologin.com/admin/login successfully but can't do the same with google script

```
function myFunction() {
  var payload = {"_u" : "user_name","_p" : "password"};
  var opt ={"payload":payload,"method":"post"};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://url.tologin.com/admin/login",opt);
  var headers = response.getAllHeaders(); 
  Logger.log(headers);
  var cookie = headers['Set-Cookie'];     
  Logger.log(cookie);
  Logger.log(response);
  response.getContentText();  

  var header = {'Cookie':cookie};

  var opt2 = {"headers":header};

  var pagedata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://url.tologin.com/admin/sales/order/export/csv",opt2);
  Logger.log(pagedata);
}
```

I get answer from webserver with failed login page and I can't figure out what is wrong with google script

Comment: Show your cookie. Cookie should be formatted properly before sending

Comment: [20-05-06 16:17:46:741 EEST] [TELLIMISKESKUS-pohjala-pohjala=removedthecookiesecret; expires=Wed, 06-May-2020 17:17:46 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/, SR-LANG-pohjala=et; expires=Thu, 06-May-2021 13:17:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/]

Comment: What do you mean by `I get answer from webserver with failed login page`? Are you being prompted to log in again or are you getting a failed login response? Also, is the service session dependent? Apps Script is cloud-based so it could be that you're sending each request from a different IP address depending on where the script runs.

Comment: Also your second url has https twice

Comment: sorry that was typo

Comment: @RafaGuillermo response I get says that login failed. How do I determine whether service is session dependent. I don't think this is, its a simple e-commerce admin interface. Any way to debug that IP issue on my side?

Comment: I copied a cookie from browser and I can then execute GET and it returns the data

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie), The request cookie header should be of the format:

```
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3
```

> A list of name-value pairs in the form of `<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>`. Pairs in the list are separated by a semicolon and a space (`;`).

As written in the [`UrlFetchApp#HttpResponse` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAllHeaders()), `getAllHeaders()` returns

> Returns an attribute/value map of headers for the HTTP response, with **headers that have multiple values returned as arrays**.

When a array is implicitly converted to a string, it is joint using a comma `,` ,which is not a valid cookie string. You could get a formatted cookie header from a Set-cookie header using a strip function like this:

```
const getCookie = setCookie =>
   Array.isArray(setCookie) 
    ? setCookie.map(getCookie).join("; ") //get each cookie and join them by ; 
    : setCookie.split("; ")[0]//get only the first part of cookie; remove irrelevant info like `Max-Age`, `expires` etc.
```

Comment: yes, that is all clear and with `var cookie = headers['Set-Cookie'];` line I can strip cookie from the headers. The result can be seen in comments of the question.

Comment: @Tiit You don't understand. The "request" header should have this: `{Cookie: "TELLIMISKESKUS-pohjala-pohjala=removedthecookiesecret; SR-LANG-pohjala=et"}`. See this `TELLIMISKESKUS-pohjala-pohjala=removedthecookiesecret; expires=Wed, 06-May-2020 17:17:46 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/, SR-LANG-pohjala=et; expires=Thu, 06-May-2021 13:17:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/`. Even if you remove the useless stuff, you're left with `TELLIMISKESKUS-pohjala-pohjala=removedthecookiesecret, SR-LANG-pohjala=et`. Note the `,` instead of `; `. Read the references in my answer until you get it.

Answer (score 0):

I got everything working

GAS script to

1. Login and fetch cookie with POST
2. build a newCookie and use it in GET requests
3. Get CSV and parse it to replace separators when necessary
4. Upload CSV content to an active sheet

   ```
   function parseCsvResponse(csvString) {
       var retArray = [];

       var strLines = csvString.split(/\n/g);
       var strLineLen = strLines.length;
       for (var i = 0; i < strLineLen; i++) {
           var line = strLines[i];
           if (line != '') {
               retArray.push(line.replace(/"/g, "").split(/;/));
               //replace ; with separator from your CSV file
        }
       }

       return retArray;
   }

   function myFunction(sheet) {
     var payload = {'user_name' : 'username','password' : 'password'};
   //replace with values on your login page "name=user_name" and "name=password"
   //if your username contains @ send it directly or use %40 instead
     var opt ={
       'payload': payload,
       'method':'post',
       "followRedirects": false,
       "testcookie": 1
     };
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://url.tologin.com/admin/login",opt);
     //inspect the right link via Chrome inspect of your login page
     Logger.log(response);
     Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
     if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
        // Incorrect user/pass combo
     } else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
       // Logged-in
       Logger.log("Logged in");
     var headers = response.getAllHeaders(); 
     Logger.log(headers);
     var cookies = headers['Set-Cookie'];
   // Extract the cookies from the login response
     var cookieParts = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
       var arr = cookies[i].split('; ');
       cookieParts.push(arr[0]);
     }
   // Create a new cookie to send with subsequent requests
     var newCookie = cookieParts.join('; ');
     Logger.log(newCookie);
     };


     opt2 = {
       "method" : "get",    
       "headers": {
         "Cookie": newCookie
       }
     };
     var url = "https://url.tologin.com/admin/sales/order/export/csv";
     response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt2);
     var resp1=response2.getContentText();  
     var csvContent = parseCsvResponse(response2.getContentText());
     Logger.log(resp1);
     Logger.log(csvContent);
   // clear everything in the sheet
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();

     // set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
     sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvContent.length /* rows */, csvContent[0].length /* columns */).setValues(csvContent);
   }
   ```

then

1. Import myFunction to sheet "Tools > Macros > Import"
2. First run asks for Google authentication of your App where myFunction is
3. Run myFunction "Tools > Macros > myFunction"
4. And you get correctly formatted CSV data to your sheet